# What is 'Select 0 from' doing in this kind of code?

Tags: sql

Can someone help me understand what the 'Select 0 from '

```
delete from table1
    where cond1 and cond2 and cond3
        and not exists
        ( select 0  from table2 where cond1 and cond2 )
```

I tried looking into some SO threads that were talking on the matter, but it was a bit too complicated to understand in a short read, speaking about optimization etc. Is there any simple explanation to what's going on here ?

Comment: You can replace the `0` with whatever you want(`NULL`, `1`, `56456456`, `Foo`, `Column1`), it doesn't matter and is ignored, actually no data at all is returned (at least in SQL-Server).

Answer (score 11):

`SELECT 0 FROM table` does not return any column values of the table but rather a constant for every row of `table` - e.g. if you have the following table

```
TABLE
id | name   | age
0  | John   | 12
1  | Jack   | 22
2  | Martin | 42
```

and the following statement

```
SELECT 0 FROM table WHERE age > 12
```

this would result in

```
0
0
```

since only the two rows with ages 22 & 42 (IDS 1 & 2 respectively) have ages greater than 12.

Comment: Thats a nice example! I was going to ask if 0 is returned COUNT(*) number of times (if we replace '0' in subquery with count(*) ). So i guess it does. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this select 0 useful? I mean what is its purpose since we can use count in case we want to learn the rows number

Comment: @jkonst: sometimes it`s better to use 'SELECT 0' than COUNT() because of the performance gain when used together with 'EXISTS'. It saves SQL Servers resources, e.g.: 'IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Deleted )' will immediately break and return true after first row is found (will then return the '0').

Answer (score 3):

If the sub-query returns 1 (or more rows), no DELETE will be performed.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic SQL for this would be:

```
delete from table1
where cond1 and cond2 and cond3
    and not exists
    ( select *  from table2 where cond1 and cond2 )
```

And the important keyword to focus on is `exists`. So this query will delete rows from `table1` if `cond1`, `cond2` and `cond3` are all true, and if there are *no* rows in `table2` where (inner) `cond1` and `cond2` are true.

Some database products (notably, ancient versions of SQL Server, I think the pre-2000 versions) actually did more work than was required when given the `exists (select * ...` form and so it became a conventional practice to substitute a constant value (`0` or `1`) so that it didn't go to the effort of retrieving any actual data. As I said, we're just checking whether rows exist, we don't care about their contents.

In any version of SQL Server you use these days, `exists (select * ...` is fine, the optimizer understands it. Other database products may or may not have issues with this form.

Answer (score 2):

`exists` checks if the following subquery returns something which means the join had at least one link (if the subquery is joining which is unclear in your pseudo code).

It is totally irrelevant what the subquery returns. In this case it is `0`.

Comment: A short example would help a lot. I'm finding it hard to understand the significance of the subquery if what is being returned is irrelevant to the outer query..

Comment: If the conditions in your subquery are `true` then it returns one or more records. If they are `false`, then it returns no records. Not even one. `exists` checks if at least one record is returned. But `exists` does not care if the returned records contains content like `0` or `1` or `hello`. It just checks if there is **something**.

Comment: So basically its like a boolean condition checking.. dont care how many things are returned, just tell me if something returns or not. And if something is returned, NOT EXISTS turns the true into a false, which in turn makes the whole OUTER Where have 'false' as outcome, and thus, nothing gets deleted!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, according to your query, the `SELECT 0` only verifies the conditions in your `WHERE` clause.
So if the condition is true, your sub query will return `0`.

Then the `NOT EXISTS` will check if your sub-query is returning a value.. IN other word, it will `DELETE` if the conditions set in the subquery does `NOT EXIST`.