# How to use UNION in Django + add fake columns

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to convert the following query in django ORM:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(date) AS Month,
    col1,
    col2,
    col3 col3,
    SUM(col4) col4,
    SUM(col5) col5
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2018-07-19' AND '2018-10-17'
GROUP BY 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    MONTH(date) AS Month,
    col1,
    col2,
    0 col3,
    SUM(col4) col4,
    0 col5
FROM
    table2
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2018-07-19' AND '2018-10-17'
GROUP BY 1 , 2 , 3 , 4
```

in MySQL Workbench that works good. But in django I see errors - I cannot do this like this:

```
result2 = table2.objects.\
        filter( date__range=( self.data['start_date'], self.data['end_date'] ) ).\
            annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).\
        values("month", "col1", "col2", "0").\
            annotate( col4=Sum('col4'), col5=Sum(0))
```

Because "Cannot resolve keyword '0' into field."

Do you have any ideas for this one ?would like to create 2 the same objects and then use *union()* to merge tables

I am using django 1.11

Comment: Hi @akaribi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like the problem is using the value `0` as a field name. Do you have to use that, or can you rename the field to a text string? I think what you are trying to do is similar this [SO Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941858/what-is-select-0-from-doing-in-this-kind-of-code) -- you don't need to use `0` to _not_ retrieve all the data. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using UNION? Django ORM doesn't have anything like UNION, but it's possible to convert queryset results to python objects and do a union on python data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a column with a fixed value to your queryset, you can use [*Value expressions*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Value, IntegerField

result2 = table2.objects.annotate(col5=Value(0, output_field=IntegerField())
```